# Google Geocoding API hangs on the load

Tags: javascript, xml, dynamics-crm-2011, google-geocoder, xmldom

I'm trying to use Google's GeoCoding API within Dynamics CRM 2011 and am having problems. I've written the following JavaScript function:

```
function geocodeXML()
{
    var mDataPath = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=WV1+1UL&sensor=false";
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    alert(1);
    xmlDoc.load(mDataPath);
    alert(2);
    var theLat = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var theLng = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lng")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    alert(theLat + ", " + theLng);
}
```

I've run this locally on my computer and it works fine - it runs through the code and gives me an alert box with the latitude and longitude. However, as soon as I include it in CRM, it refuses to run. I've added alert boxes as above and it's the line inbetween the two alerts (xmlDoc.load(mDataPath);) that's causing the problem. I get the alert box with "1" in it and then nothing else. I've tried including the code in a CRM function (which gives me an "Access is denied" error for some reason) and I've tried wrapping it in HTML and including it as an iframe.

I have seen that this API returns a tag called "Status" which should give responses like "OK", "ZERO_RESULTS", "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", "INVALID_REQUEST", etc so I know it's not an issue with quotas or the syntax of my request - it's as if the API can't be reached from the server at that address. As I've said, running the code locally work fine and I get a response from the API (with a status of "OK") but as soon as it's in CRM, it returns nothing.

I really am at a loss as to what could be causing this and I'd appreciate any help that can be offered.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use it in an iFrame?

Comment: I've tried both - without any luck. However, I've found another thread on here which has, sort of, answered my question. It looks like, as it's a cross-domain request, that I can't do it with this method. There's a JavaScript API as opposed to an XMLHTTP one that is more useful - I haven't got it working as I'd like yet, but it is returning information from Google Maps which is more than this one did.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to change browser settings to make this work as you are attempting to make a cross-site call from script.

Go to Security Settings in IE. From Miscellaneous select "Access data sources across domains" and enable it. From Scripting go to "Enable XSS filter" and disable it. Not really optimal but I think it might work for you - and at least confirm for you that it is a cross-site scripting issue.

If you put this in an IFRAME - worth at least testing - make sure you enable cross site scripting in the IFRAME setup.